# Join and showing different columns from tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have a simple SQL question, I thought it would be quite straight forward but have got myself in a muddle. Any help would be appreciated

I have table A which contains a last updated
Table A has a one to many with Table B
Table B has a one to many with Table C

I want to show all rows of table C with the last updated time from table A. I have tried some joins but they dont seem to be quite working. Ideally I want somehting like

```
select a.lastUpdated c.* from TableA a, TableC c where
a.id in (select a_id from TableB where (select b_id from TableC where c_id = select 
id  from TableC where XXXX=YYYY))
```

so I can pass in an id for table C and then get one row returned with the last updated time present.

XXX=YYY would be my criteria for returning one row of table C.

Any help or pointers appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM TableA AS a 
    INNER JOIN TableB AS b 
    ON a.a_id = b.b_id 
        INNER JOIN TableC AS c 
        ON b.b_id = c.c_id 
WHERE a.lastUpdated = c.lastUpdated;
```

Should work. This is a situation where a striaght `INNER JOIN` should suffice; unless of course I have missed something.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by joining A and B together, aggregating the results at the c_id level, and then joining in C:

```
select tc.*, maxlastupdated
from tablec tc left outer join
     (select tb.c_id, max(lastupdated) as maxlastupdated
      from tablea ta join
           tableb tb
           on ta.b_id = tb.b_id
      group by ta.id
     ) ta
     on tc.c_id = ta.c_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *drive* your SQL query from Table C.
The query below displays the updated timestamp column from table A.
Since it is a one-to-many in the direction of tables A --> B --> C
You will inevitably end-up with a lot of rows in table C - all with the same timestamp.

```
SELECT c.*, a1.update_timestamp 
FROM table_c c, table_b b, table_a a1
WHERE c.join_column = b.join_column
AND b.join_column = a1.join_column
AND a1.update_timestamp =
(SELECT max(a2.update_timestamp) FROM table_a a2
WHERE a2.<identifying columns> = a1.<identifying columns>
);
```